# Apply CSS to active router link [Angular 2]

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, angular

I would like to apply special CSS style properties to active router links:

```html
<a [routerLink]='link'>{{name}}</a>
```

Here is what I tried so far (Using the default router-link-active class):

```css
.router-link-active {
 color: #000;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

It doesn't work and I really don't understand why.

Comment: I don't think it's actually a duplicate; the other question was for Angular 1, while this is angular2, and angular2's router is several versions removed from angular1's.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Currently Angular 2 has a [built in attribute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html) that you can use on any link that is used with `[routerLink]` it is `routerLinkActive` so all you need to do is have:

```
<a [routerLink]='link' routerLinkActive="router-link-active">{{name}}</a>
```

and then it will recognize which route is the current active route and apply your router-link-active class.

NOTE:

For those who are using routerLink on tags other than `a` tags, (personally i am using it on a button) `routerLinkActive` doesn't work but should work on the next release of the router - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9755

Comment: this works fine, and how can I get a boolean inside my component typescript class indicating if the router link is active or not?

Comment: So... is it that you just need to know if there is an element on your page that has the router-link-active class? or are you trying to find out which route is currently active?

Comment: I want to find out which route is currently active, actually I have a single router link in a TabComponent's template and I then generate many router links using *ngFor in a parent component

Comment: In that case you would need to look into using [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html) it returns everything you could want and more about the component that has been loaded. If you end up having troubles implementing it, please create a new question

Comment: Works with released 2.0 version too.

Comment: however if you add a click function to the a-tag and change the location based on #href tag - it drops the pseudo active class styling -- so how would you bind that <a> tag to an id on the page once clicked?

Answer (score 3):

The new router has a directive called "[routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html)" which is what your interested in.

Ex.`<a [routerLink]="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link">Bob</a>`

"When the url is either '/user' or '/user/bob', the active-link class will be added to the a tag. If the url changes, the class will be removed."

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything more, this is the direction I would point you in.

```html
<a [routerLink]='link' [ngClass]="{'router-link-active': routerLink.something === something}">{{name}}</a>
```

If `routerLink.something === something`, or whatever expression you want, evaluates to true, the class (and styling) will be applied.